# Angular Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, typescript

When I click the button in the car-detail.component.html file, I want to go to rental.component.html file. But I'm getting an error. How can I resolve this error?

My app-routing.module file
[image: My app-routing.module file]

HTML file I added to the routerlink
[image: HTML file I added to the routerlink]

The error I get when I click the button is this
[image: The error I get when I click the button is this:]

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating your html to `routerLink="/rental/{{car.carId}}"` should do the trick.

Here is a reference to the Angular docs for routerLink: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#relative-link-paths

> The first segment name can be prepended with /, ./, or ../.
>
> - If the first segment begins with /, the router looks up the route from the root of the app.
> - If the first segment begins with ./, or doesn't begin with a slash, the router looks in the children of the current activated
>   route.
> - If the first segment begins with ../, the router goes up one level in the route tree.

So in your case, you are on the route `cars/:carId`, and since your routerLink doesn't start with a `/, ./ or ../` it is looking relative to the current route and looking at its children(which there aren't any). You need to update it to look for a route at the root level. Adding the `/` at the beginning of the route will accomplish that.

Comment: No, this is a very simple mistake. I wasted time in vain for hours. Thank you very much. I solved it thanks to you.